# Definition of proposition in a constructive setting

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

In a typical discrete math course, we are taught that a proposition is something that is either true or false but not both, which seems to be based on a classical interpretation.

How would one go about defining a proposition in a constructive setting?

Maybe "something that we may attempt to provide evidence for"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useful references:

- A.Heyting, [Intuitionism: An Introduction (3rd ed. 1971)](https://books.google.it/books?id=prhLAAAAMAAJ), page 24:

> We only assert a proposition if we can prove it; so we only assert that either $a=0$ or $b=0$ if we can prove one of these propositions.

See also Errett Bishop, [Foundations of constructive analysis (McGraw-Hill, 1967)](https://books.google.it/books?id=G4OBMQEACAAJ&), *Preface*, page viii, dealing with the "pragmatic content" of mathematical statements:

> It appears that there are certain mathematical statements that are merely evocative, which make assertions without empirical validity.

In a nutshell, according to [Intuitionsim (and most constructivists)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/):

> knowing [*asserting*] that a statement $A$ is true means having a proof of it.